# Scrapy not scraping https?

Tags: python, https, web-scraping, scrapy

New to scrapy so I may just be doing stuff wrong. It seems however that scrapy won't scrape any https sites I feed into it.

```
class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "SeleniumSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.facebook.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\.html', )), callback='parse_page',follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.stop()
        print self.verificationErrors
        CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        hxs.select('//div').extract()
```

Output:

```
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.22.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS': 'dirbot.items.Website', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'dirbot.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['dirbot.spiders']}    
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState  
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats  
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: FilterWordsPipeline
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [SeleniumSpider] INFO: Spider opened
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [SeleniumSpider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [SeleniumSpider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.facebook.com> (referer: None)
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [SeleniumSpider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-05-30 11:22:01-0400 [SeleniumSpider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Any suggestions? Crawler works fine on http://www.amazon.com and others

Comment: When i was trying to scrape facebook it would give me the same issues. I think facebook did something tricky.

Comment: I tried other https sites and was getting the same results.... have you had any success on other https sites?

Comment: Not using Scrapy, I usually just use urllib2 by itself and get all the data that way.

Comment: any good tutorials on that? I'm not stuck to scrapy if urllib2 isn't extremly difficult.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing to do with `https`. The problem is that there are really no links containing `.html`.

Here's how you can test it:

```
class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "SeleniumSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.facebook.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        print hxs.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "html")]').extract()
```

It would output an empty list.

Instead of crawling facebook html pages, you should really use [facebook SDK for python](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) or [`pyfacebook`](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/), it is more convenient and robust. I'm pretty sure it would not be fun at all to parse facebook pages using scrapy because there is so many dynamic javascript logic, ajax calls etc involved in constructing the pages on facebook.

UPD (general rule for extracting all of the links):

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a more general crawler that will work on http and https. Also attempting to use selenium to take care of the dynamic stuff.

Comment: is there a way to fix my spider to actually crawl https sites?

Comment: @Neppinger it actually crawls https sites. I've provided an example, see what is inside the `response` in the `parse()` callback - it is a facebook page there.

Comment: I guess then my next question would be is there a broad Rule you can use for spiders that allows them to crawl through most webpages regardless of .html pages or etc.

Comment: @Neppinger see the UPD section - just don't provide any arguments to `SgmlLinkExtractor` constructor.